How do we find $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right]$
How do we find
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right]$$
I know that the limit is $0$ but I don't know how to apply l'Hopital's rule to this problem.
I rewrote the function as
$$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{x}{x+1}}$$
and took $x \to 0^+$ and got $\frac{0}{0}$, an indeterminate form. But when I try applying l'Hopital's rule I get
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}}$$
which doesn't look like a much simpler expression.
What can I do here?

Possible Duplicate: How to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{e^{-1/x}}{x} = 0$

This is a different function.

Your question is the same as $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$.

Put $t=\frac{1}{x}$, then you have $t\to +\infty$ when $x\to 0^+$.
Therefore, you can rewrite the limit as follows:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{t\to +\infty}(1+t)e^{-t}=0$$

This is same as $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {1+x} {e^{x}}$ which is $0$ by L'Hopital's Rule.

"By applying the substitution $x \mapsto \frac1x$ [...]"
